# Is there a way in jQuery to detected if an element has already a bound event?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to detected if an element already has a bound event ?

In other words I want to bind an event only if the element hasn't bound it before.. otherwise I'm triggering it twice.

I'm using jQuery 1.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#someId').data('events')
```

should give you the events that are bound to this element.

Comment: I've had some trouble with this method before (although it is the only one I know of). I suspect if the event is bound using .live and not .bind this gets flaky. Just a caution :)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov thanks, I see, how can I count them ? I need a true/false result.. I've tried adding .length but it doesn't work. Please consider I'm using jQuery 1.2.7

Comment: @lnrbob thanks for the caution. I actually don't have live() since I'm using an old jquery version

Comment: @Patrick, `if ($('#someId').data('events')['click']) { alert('click is assigned'); } else { alert('click is not assigned'); }`.

Comment: @Darin - presumably you could set a variable or return true or false rather than firing an alert?

Comment: @lnrbob, you could do whatever you want, I just illustrated how to test if a `click` event handler has been assigned to a given element.

Answer (score 1):

**If anyone stumbles upon this post. This has been changed in the newer versions of jQuery.**

The current code to access the list of events bound to an element is as follows...

Using an ID (2 ways):

```
$._data($('#IDValue')[0]).events
$._data($('#IDValue')[0], "events")
```

Using a class (2 ways):

```
$._data($('.classValue')[0], "events")
$._data($('.classValue')[0]).events
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Darin is the right one but in such cases, I prefer to add a class to the elements when the function is bound and check if the class is added when I am trying to bound to the elements

eg.

```
$('a').each(function(index, elem) {
  if ($(elem).hasClass('added')) {
     return;
  }
  else {
     $(elem).click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
     })
     .addClass("added");
  }
})
```